# Verificando preenchimento de colunas com o CHECK

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, case

Estou criando o BD da meu TCC e a table Clients está:

```
create table clients(
id serial primary key,
name varchar(255),
cpf varchar(11),
cnpj varchar(14),
....
```

Pensei em fazer um CHECK limitando o preenchimento OU do CPF OU do CNPJ, no caso nunca os 2 podem estar vazios.. óbvio que vou fazer isso no back, mas queria uma segurança no BD também, como faço isso?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

No seu caso, eu conheço uma solução com TRIGGER, segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  FieldA INT,
  FieldB INT
);

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER InsertFieldABNotNull BEFORE INSERT ON foo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.FieldA IS NULL AND NEW.FieldB IS NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '\'FieldA\' and \'FieldB\' cannot both be null';
  END IF;
END//
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateFieldABNotNull BEFORE UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.FieldA IS NULL AND NEW.FieldB IS NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '\'FieldA\' and \'FieldB\' cannot both be null';
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO foo (FieldA, FieldB) VALUES (NULL, 10); -- OK
INSERT INTO foo (FieldA, FieldB) VALUES (10, NULL); -- OK
INSERT INTO foo (FieldA, FieldB) VALUES (NULL, NULL); -- gives error
UPDATE foo SET FieldA = NULL; -- gives error
```

Fiddle com o exemplo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Hvg8qFvBEiGUimk9ySQab/0

Para PostgreSQL basta criar uma Trigger que retorne NULL, ex:

```
create table stuff (
  stuff_id int primary key,
  thing text
);

create or replace function stuff_inserting() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin

  return null;

end $$;

insert into stuff values (1, 'asdf');

select * from stuff; /* returns 1 row */

create trigger inserting before insert on stuff for each row execute procedure stuff_inserting();

insert into stuff values (2, 'fdsa');

select * from stuff; /* still returns only 1 row */
```

Comment: Show de bola, mas no Postgres não funciona correto?

Comment: A lógica funciona sim, basta criar uma trigger que retorne null. coloquei um exemplo de trigger com null de retorno na resposta.

Comment: Não manjo dessa parte de triggers, na verdade nunca fiz uso, apesar de saber que é de grande utilidade, mas se puderes me dar uma ajuda agradeço.
Obviamente o Postgres utiliza algumas funções diferentes do Mysql, mas podes me ajudar a colocar uma mensagem?

O que fiz até agora foi:
[https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sJLeGX8tQybn4o87hnN8n1/0]

Isto para Postgres funcionou aqui, só não retornou nenhuma mensagem pois:
`USING MESSAGE = cpf || ' and ' || cnpf || ' cannot both be null';`
Gera uma mensagem nada a ver, tens como me ajudar nisso? Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Sobre a resposta do meu problema, consegui resolver com a ajuda do Diego Marques:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario(
id serial, 
cpf varchar(20),
cnpj varchar(20)
);
create or replace function cpfcnpjVerification() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
IF (NEW.cpf IS NULL AND NEW.cnpj IS NULL) THEN
  RAISE SQLSTATE '09000'
  USING MESSAGE = 'Column CPF and CNPJ cannot both be null';
END IF;

return NEW;
end $$;

create trigger InsertCpfCnpjNotNull before insert on usuario 
for each row execute procedure cpfcnpjVerification();
```

---

```
INSERT INTO usuario(cpf, cnpj) VALUES('22','33') -- normal
INSERT INTO usuario(cpf, cnpj) VALUES(NULL,'44') -- normal
INSERT INTO usuario(cpf, cnpj) VALUES('55',NULL) -- normal
INSERT INTO usuario(cpf, cnpj) VALUES(NULL,NULL) -- ERROR: Column CPF and CNPJ cannot both be null
                                                 --SQL state: 09000
                                                 --Context: PL/pgSQL function cpfcnpjverification() line 4 at RAISE
```

Uma dúvida que eu fiquei foi em relação ao SQL STATE, qual utilizar, mas baseado em [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/errcodes-appendix.html) escolhi o 09000 apesar de eu pensar que não faça tanta diferença para mim.

Obrigado